# Antlr deep rule set performance issue

Tags: antlr4, context-free-grammar

I've tried making a grammar that understands expression priorities for a C#-like language:

```
var a = expression0.expression1(expression2 + expression3() * expression4)
```

When correctly prioritized becomes:

```
var a = (expression0.expression1)(expression2 + ((expression3()) * expression4))
```

To achieve that, I've sorted the expressions into rules by priority. Here's the relevant excerpt from my grammar:

```
expression: assignmentExpression;
assignmentExpression
    : equalityExpression ASSIGNMENT assignmentExpression
    | equalityExpression
    ;
equalityExpression
    : logicalExpression equals equalityExpression
    | logicalExpression notEquals equalityExpression
    | logicalExpression
    ;
logicalExpression
    : relationalExpression and logicalExpression
    | relationalExpression or logicalExpression
    | relationalExpression
    ;
relationalExpression
    : addExpression greaterThan relationalExpression
    | addExpression lessThan relationalExpression
    | addExpression greaterOrEquals relationalExpression
    | addExpression lessOrEquals relationalExpression
    | addExpression
    ;
addExpression
    : multiplyExpression add addExpression
    | multiplyExpression subtract addExpression
    | multiplyExpression
    ;
multiplyExpression
    : conversionExpression multiply multiplyExpression
    | conversionExpression divide multiplyExpression
    | conversionExpression
    ;
conversionExpression
    : unaryExpression AS conversionExpression
    | unaryExpression
    ;
unaryExpression
    : subtract unaryExpression
    | add unaryExpression
    | ifExpression
    ;
ifExpression
    : IF PAREN expression ENDPAREN expression (ELSE expression)?
    | instantiationExpression
    ;
instantiationExpression
    : NEW invocationExpression
    | invocationExpression
    ;
invocationExpression
    : reachExpression PAREN arguments? ENDPAREN
    | reachExpression
    ;
reachExpression
    : primeExpression DOT primeExpression
    | primeExpression
    ;
```

Using it on the following code:

```
{ int a = 7 }
```

Produces the following output:

```
expression
 assignmentExpression
  equalityExpression
   logicalExpression
    relationalExpression
     addExpression
      multiplyExpression
       conversionExpression
        unaryExpression
         ifExpression
          instantiationExpression
           invocationExpression
            reachExpression
             primeExpression
              blockExpression
               "{"
               statement
                variableDeclaration
                 variableType
                  type
                   identifier
                    "int"
                 identifier
                  "a"
                 variableInitialization
                  "="
                  expression
                   assignmentExpression
                    equalityExpression
                     logicalExpression
                      relationalExpression
                       addExpression
                        multiplyExpression
                         conversionExpression
                          unaryExpression
                           ifExpression
                            instantiationExpression
                             invocationExpression
                              reachExpression
                               primeExpression
                                literal
                                 integer
                                  "7"
               "}"
```

It probably has problems, but I can't really test it, since this kind of grammar incurs a crazy performance penalty. My previous grammar that parsed expressions left to right took a couple of milliseconds to parse, and this one takes 2 whole minutes.

I've tracked it down to `ParserATNSimulator.AdaptivePredict`, and deeper inside, the issue is a crazy deep stack of

```
ParserATNSimulator.Closure
ParserATNSimulator.ClosureCheckingStopState
ParserATNSimulator.Closure_
```

Instead of going down the rabbit hole once to get to the correct expression (number literal: 7), it seems to go all the way down once for every rule level. So instead of this being O(n), it takes O(n^n) just to get to that damn "7".

Is this an issue with Antlr, my grammar or just the way it is?

---

EDIT:
OK, I've managed to eliminate the performance issue by rewriting my grammar in this style:

```
assignmentExpression: equalityExpression (ASSIGNMENT assignmentExpression)?;
```

But I still don't understand why this happens and how did this change solve the issue.

Comment: You don't need to encode precedence with multiple expression rules like that in ANTLR4. You can just use a single left-recursive expression rule with the alternatives listed in descending order of precedence and `<assoc=right>` annotations for the rules that are supposed to be right associative.

Comment: Are you sure that's true? How would I then encode rules that are supposed to have the same priority (be evalauted left to right)?

Comment: As `expression op=('+'|'-') expression` or `expression additiveOp expression` where `additiveOp` is defined as `'+' | '-'`. Take a look at the [Java 8 ANTLR 4 grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/JavaParser.g4#L468) to see this in action on a grammar for a real-life language.

Comment: ok, thanks, gonna try that

Comment: Also, don't measure the first parse run for a given input. ANTLR4 has a significant warmup phase (building internal structures for the paths taken by a specific input). Once this is done further parse runs are much faster.

Comment: Oh, interesting